# Contact Form with Django 3, G Suite - email sending error

Tags: python, django, email, digital-ocean, google-workspace

**Goal**

- Deploying a landing page on Digital Ocean built with Django 3.
- Adding my G suite account to the contact form so people can type in their email, subject, message and send it to me.

**What I have done**

- I have built my contact from with the following [guide](https://wsvincent.com/django-contact-form/).
- I have tested it and it prints out all the parameters in the terminal as it should

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: helllo
From: customeremail@gmail.com
To: admin@example.com
Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 14:29:40 -0000
Message-ID: <12121212121212.1222212121212.1212121212121212@mymachinename.local>
This is the message.
```

- After I have finished the tutorial I have added/switched the following things to the settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mayname@mycompanydomain.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

- I have purchased a G Suite subscription that contains G Suite SMTP relay service that can send 10'000 email/day.

**ERRORS**

1.After the 1st run I have received the following e-mail:

```
Sign-in attempt was blocked
myname@businessemaildomainname.com
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account from a non-Google app. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened. Review your account activity to make sure no one else has access.
Check activity
```

2.After the 2nd run I have received the following error message in the browser (and no email)

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /email/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 121sdgsdf.12 - gsmtp')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
```

3.After seeking with google help chat and switching up a bunch of settings than running the same code again

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /email/
(111, b"5.7.0 Mail relay denied [1111:1a1a:111a:1111:1aaa:aaa:a11aa:aa11a]. 
Invalid\n5.7.0 credentials for relay for one of the domains in: 
myusername.local,\n5.7.0 mydomainname.com (as obtained from HELO and MAIL FROM).\n5.7.0 
Email is being sent from a domain or IP address which isn't registered\n5.7.0 
in your G Suite account. Please login to your G Suite account and\n5.7.0 
verify that your sending device IP address has been registered within\n5.7.0 
the G Suite SMTP Relay Settings. For more information, please visit\n5.7.0
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6140680#maildenied 1aa1a1a1a1k.111 - gsmtp", 'thecontactfillercustomeremail@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with G-mail even if you get it working after a while google going to cut it of when it hurts the most. A better solution would be to use some of the following solutions

- sendgrid.com
- mailjet.com
- icontact.com
- mailgun.com

Comment: If you're spamming, yes, most certainly. We're sending emails that react to user actions like "welcome to the platform" or "here's your confirmation code", that kind of think, for many years know. So far, Google didn't just pull plug on us.